# resteasy-cdi breaks deployment to Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, tomcat7, resteasy

I am developing a simple REST server using resteasy 3.0.6.Final, which is deployed to tomcat 7.0.50.

According to the [official doc](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html_single/#d4e111), there are basically two ways to do it:

1. using ServletContainerInitializer, which is implemented in the package `resteasy-servlet-initializer`.
2. using `web.xml` and servlet dispatcher.

I have tried the approaches and they both worked for me.

Now I want to add CDI support using WELD, and to do that I need to add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

to my war/WEB-INF/lib.

However, this breaks the deployment.  Tomcat shows only the following error message in catalina.out:

```
Jan 20, 2014 10:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Jan 20, 2014 10:24:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/storage] startup failed due to previous errors
```

There are many suggestions online about removing resteasy-cdi.  So

1. Why is resteasy-cdi breaking the deployment?  Is there a ticket documenting the problem?
2. How can I integrate resteasy with WELD otherwise?

Thanks for any help.

**Update 1**

After a session of debugging, the issue turns out to be very simple: resteasy-cdi needs a concrete CDI implementation to work, which means I should include

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

in my build.

Another note is on configuring WELD mentioned in the [official doc](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.1.2.Final/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5555).  When I include these two listeners in my web.xml,

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I got the following error in my localhost.log

```
Jan 20, 2014 11:55:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton is not set. Is your Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() set correctly?
```

I am not sure if the doc is wrong, but replacing the listeners with

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

did the trick and the war file deployed successfully.

Comment: The explanation for your problem will probably be in the "previous errors".  Check for them earlier in the logs.  If they are not there, check that your logging configs are not suppressing them and/or temporarily increase the logging level.

Comment: Ok, I finally got everything to work by adding and configuring weld-servlet to my project.  Seems resteasy-cdi needs an actual CDI implementation to work (which is understandable, since it just serves as a bridge).

Comment: @stackoverflower Would you mind posting a link to the working code? I'm using the exact same combo (RESTEasy + Weld) and my injected bean is always null. My code is slightly different in that it is Groovy, built using Gradle and deployed to Jetty, but if that is my problem, we are back to the dark age of vendor dependence.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, here's the link to the main configuration files.  https://gist.github.com/ryan-ju/8907085

Comment: @stackoverflower thank you. What I was missing and is surprisingly absent from your gist is the following. Once I added that, CDI kicked in.
    <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.injector.factory</param-name>
      <param-value>org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory</param-value>
    </context-param>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the `Singleton is not set` exception in the [official weld forum](http://community.jboss.org/thread/236446) and it is a bug in the docs. As you did, you should use the 'original' `org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener`.